# How to find the most common string(s) in a Python list?

Tags: python

I am dealing with ancient DNA data. I have an array with n different base pair calls for a given coordinate.

e.g.,
['A','A','C','C','G']

I need to setup a bit in my script whereby the most frequent call(s) are identified. If there is one, it should use that one. If there are two (or three) that are tied (e.g., A and C here), I need it randomly pick one of the two.

I have been looking for a solution but cannot find anything satisfactory. The most frequent solution, I see is Counter, but Counter is useless for me as c.most_common(1) will not identify that 1 and 2 are tied.

Comment: Why not just count the number of each base and then compare the counts? If there's a tie, "flip a coin" with random. If you need to do larger than 1 base, have a sliding window

Comment: You won't find something faster than DeadChex answer either.

Comment: @Prune I've re-opened the question since the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47286816/python-specific-count-of-chars-in-string) you linked to is entirely different from this question.

Comment: Yup; I linked to "how to count"; I somehow spaced on the last, critical paragraph.  Thanks for cleaning up after me.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the maximum count from the mapping returned by `Counter` with the `max` function first, and then ues a list comprehension to output only the keys whose counts equal the maximum count. Since `Counter`, `max`, and list comprehension all cost linear time, the overall time complexity of the code can be kept at *O(n)*:

```
from collections import Counter
import random
lst = ['A','A','C','C','G']
counts = Counter(lst)
greatest = max(counts.values())
print(random.choice([item for item, count in counts.items() if count == greatest]))
```

This outputs either `A` or `C`.

Comment: Hard choice between the 2 solutions that are similar and good. The other is more generic & reduces imports, this one more Pythonic and compact. I'll use the random.choice function to press up ;)

Comment: Keep in mind that the other answer calls the `list.count` method in a loop over the length of the list, unnecessarily resulting in *O(n ^ 2)* in time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work:

```
import random

string = ['A','A','C','C','G']

dct = {}

for x in set(string):
    dct[x] = string.count(x)

max_value = max(dct.values())

lst = []

for key, value in dct.items():
    if value == max_value:
        lst.append(key)

print(random.choice(lst))
```